# Using a custom Excel function in a module

Tags: excel, vba, function

I have some data in two columns (length of the columns will be dynamic). The first column is of the format: Sum of 9/1/2021  - the second column are simply numbers (sample data below in the linked picture).

I want to clean that first column up and put it into a date format in another column. I created a custom function to extract the text from the first column:

```
Function ReturnCellToLeft()

    ReturnCellToLeft = Application.Caller.Cells.Offset(0, -4).Value

    'ReturnCellToLeft = Application.Caller.Cells.Offset(0, -4).Value where -4 in this case 'is the number of columns to the left where the original data is stored.

    'The formula would be =RIGHT(ReturnCellToLeft(),LEN(ReturnCellToLeft())-7) as an example to extract the text 'to the right of the "Sum of " that begins the cell.
    ' 7 is the number of characters in "Sum of "

End Function
```

This function works fine (manually if entered in a cell as a formula), but I want to use the function within a module so that it uses the values in that first column for all of the succeeding rows in the (new) column to the right.

How do I call that function within a module? I recognize I'll need a loop of some sort to go thru all of the rows.

[image: Sample data]

Comment: Why bother using this function, when you can just use `Offset` directly in the `For`/`For Each` loop you use on the Range/Column?

Comment: Why the heck would you write such a function that makes all formulas that use it slow if you can just use a formula directly. `=RIGHT(A1,LEN(A1)-7)` or `=RIGHT(RC[-4],LEN(RC[-4])-7)` That would how to do it properly.

Comment: If you want to do it that way I'd change the function so that it accepts a range rather than looking at the caller cell.  `Function ReturnCellToLeft(Target As Range)`.  Then use `Target` rather than `Application.Caller`.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Actually `Target` needs to point to that `Offset(0, -4)` cell. If the formula does not depend on that cell it won't update if that cell changes. Pointing to the caller cell does not make any sense at all. • The function as it is now does not make any sense at all unless it is made volatile it won't recalculate on source cell changes.

Comment: @Peh True.  I was just really looking at  _How do I call that function within a module?_ - pass the cell reference to the function and _I want to clean that first column up and put it into a date format in another column._ - `ReturnCellToLeft = CDate(Replace(Target, "Sum of ", ""))`.  Used as a UDF you can just drag the formula down.

Answer (score 0):

Wouldnt something like below do the job.

```
Sub DoIt()
    ActiveCell.Offset(0, 2) = Mid(ActiveCell, 8, 10)
End Sub
```

Comment: "DoIt" does it without all of the convoluted things the custom function was trying to accomplish. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

I found this worked for me and does the looping as well.

```
Sub LoopColumn()
'
' use a dynamic range to loop through data and extract the 10 rightmost 'characters which are dates in a text string

    Dim rngMyRange As Range

Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select

Set rngMyRange = Selection
    Dim c       As Range
   
'
    Range(ActiveCell, ActiveCell.End(xlDown)).Select

'
    For Each c In rngMyRange
        c = Mid(c, 8, 10)
    Next c
' formats range as short date
    rngMyRange.NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
End Sub
```